# Any shortcut to making same change to different independent particle systems at the same time?

Tags: particles, hair

I have a Scalp with ~20 different independent particle systems on it to allow for some different parameterisations. However there are some parameters that will all be the same - e.g  I want to change the diameter scale, shape etc for all 20 systems at the same time. Can do it old school ie one at a time, but wondering if there is any shortcut to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, depending on the context. I think you will be more interested in my second solution than my first, but the first is common so for completeness I'm including both.

If you're wholesale copying the properties of one particle system to another object, then you can select both while holding down control, with your object that has your particle system last, and then click the arrow next to the particle system list. It has an option in it called "Copy Active to Selected Objects", which will duplicate the system.

That said, it sounds like you have a few traits you want to adjust, but want to keep consistent across multiple systems. This can be done with *drivers*. A driver is basically a script that updates one property according to the state of another property, but the good news is you don't need to be a Python expert to use them. They also allow for changes to individual properties of your particle systems.

Start with the system that you're using for control. Right-click your parameter, in this case I'm going to assume "Emission Lifetime", and select "Copy as New Driver" from the menu.

[image: Copy As New Driver]

Then, go to your other particle system, the one you want to be controlled by this, and find the same property in it. This will work for *almost* anything. Right click its property, and choose "Paste Driver".

[image: Paste Driver]

After this, the field will turn (by default settings) purple, and you will be unable to change it directly; but any change from your other particle system, the one you copied the driver from, will be immediately reflected here too. It works for all kinds of data types, and most data.

[image: Driver implemented]

If you need to remove it, this can also be done with right click; and if you have a knack for scripting and want to change it or make it vary, relative to one or more other properties in the file, in some way, explore the Edit Driver option and know that it's basically standard Python syntax.

That should do it for most of your properties.

Comment: Many thanks for the speedy reply  and goes a long way for me. Just wondering if there there is any way to do this for > 1 item at a time? eg select "strand shape, diameter root, tip, diameter scale" on one particle group, then go to the 2nd one and paste them in 1 pass, and then onto the 3rd etc etc ? Really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Well, once you've got your driver copied, there's no reason you can't paste it on multiple properties of other objects... for something as diverse as what you're discussing, I might write a Python script to do it, but that's a little advanced and would probably only barely save you some time. Unless someone else comes along with an idea, you might just have to "power through" this one.

Comment: Understood and many thanks again for confirming. Looks like time to learn python for me but for now your first solution is a great help.